# how to run infinite loop in background android

Tags: android, loops, background

I have a client in android connected to a server in c++ using TCP sockets.
I need my app to constantly send an image to the server. I tried using an infinite(while) loop, but then my app does not do anything else while running the loop, and I need my app to constantly send the image but also be able to run tasks at the same time.
this is my code:

```
    class sendImage implements Runnable{
    @Override
    public void run() {
        while(true){
              try {
                    Bitmap bmp=screenShot();
                    ByteArrayOutputStream bosBitmap = new ByteArrayOutputStream(); 
                    bmp.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 50, bosBitmap); 
                    byte[] arrayBitmap = bosBitmap.toByteArray();   

                    OutputStream os = socket.getOutputStream();
                    BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
                    DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(bos);
                    dos = new DataOutputStream(os);
                    dos.write(arrayBitmap, 0, arrayBitmap.length);
                    dos.flush();
                    memecontentView.destroyDrawingCache();  
            } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }       
    }
}
```

and when I click a button this is how I initialize the thread

```
public void onClick(View view) {
    new Thread(new sendImage()).start();
}
```

But when I click the button, the image is sent but it does not allow me to do anything else, if I press another button, my app closes
How can I run an infinite loop that allows my app to perform other tasks at the same time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to keep threads running for long periods of time, it is highly recommended you use the various APIs provided by the java.util.concurrent pacakge such as Executor, ThreadPoolExecutor and FutureTask.

Comment: I changed my code implementing a Thread, but my app does not allow me to do anything else. How can I make the infinite loop run in background so it allows to do some other tasks ? I updated the code.

Answer (score 1):

I just implemented an AsyncTask, it works great:

```
public class SendImage extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>{
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0){
        while(true){
              try {
                    Bitmap bmp=screenShot();
                    ByteArrayOutputStream bosBitmap = new ByteArrayOutputStream(); 
                    bmp.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 30, bosBitmap); 
                    byte[] arrayBitmap = bosBitmap.toByteArray();   
                    
                    OutputStream os = socket.getOutputStream();
                    BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
                    DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(bos);
                    dos = new DataOutputStream(os);
                    dos.write(arrayBitmap, 0, arrayBitmap.length);
                    dos.flush();
                    memecontentView.destroyDrawingCache();  
            } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }       
    }
}
```

Comment: AsyncTasks are not good for longer background processes. Check Android documents.

Comment: Thanks for the information, which other kind of thread do you recommend me to use?